# Jasper: Render header of a table only if at least one table row can be fit

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table in jasper report:

```
    <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
      <componentElement>
        <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="504" height="75" uuid="eb4057df-dd6a-40dd-870e-baac8c8afe17">
          <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="inch"/>
          <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="inch"/>
          <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
          <datasetRun subDataset="Table LineItems" uuid="8a44aec8-cdd4-4be3-b47a-620e00bb910a">
            <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
              <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{info}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
            <datasetParameter name="currency">
              <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{info2}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
            </datasetParameter>
          </datasetRun>
          <jr:column width="35" uuid="b265983c-c6a0-4806-8b61-d5b17499f2d4">
            <jr:columnHeader style="table 1_CH" height="20" rowSpan="1">
              <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
              </box>
              <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="35" height="20" uuid="2e0a43fe-aa8a-442f-a6b3-272d10ecc309"/>
                <box>
                  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                  <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{info.name} +"#"]]></textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </jr:columnHeader>
            <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
              <box>
                <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
              </box>
              <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="35" height="20" uuid="6eef6bae-b45e-4597-82d7-72cbad709c6b"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="2">
                  <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                  <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{infoTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
              </textField>
            </jr:detailCell>
          </jr:column>
        </jr:table>
      </componentElement>
    </band>
```

In the code I have removed other columns for brevity.
The contents of the </jr:detailCell> are dynamic and can be of any length. Thus the height of table rows are dynamic. And this table is also of dynamic height and is positioned dynamically. Hence, the table may render in any part of the report. So, I only want the table header to be printed if at least one table row can be fit into the page too. If only the page header is rendered and the rest of the table rows are rendered separately in another page, it looks bad. As the table row is of dynamic height, I cannot apply the solution of specifying the band height as a sum of the table row and table header. Also, I can't seem to use group headers so I cannot use that trick.  Any suggestions?

Comment: A simple solution would be to put it in a group and set minHeightToStartNewPage it's not exactly what you want because you need to set min height manually, but it comes close.. Hence you define how much space there must be left on page or otherwise move to next page.

Comment: But the problem is the heights are dynamic so I cannot set the min height